# Javascript Eval / Execute code from input box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, compilation, eval

Edit: It is popup in google extension..

I want to execute code from input box..

```
function jsinjector() {
    var jsinjectinvar = document.getElementById("jsinjectin").value;
    eval(jsinjectionvar);       
}
```

Input box and button:

```
<input type="text" id="jsinjectin" name="jsinjectin" class="javascriptinject" />

<input type="button" class="javascriptinject" name="jsinjectsub" id="jsinjectsub" value="Inject" onmouseup="jsinjector();" />
```

Eval didn't work, so what is wrong?

-Thanks, beginner Sam

Comment: You're setting `jsinjectinvar` but evaluating `jsinjectionvar`. Missing an "o" in the first one.

Comment: The Javascript console would have told you that `jsinjectionvar` was undefined: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Still doesn't work..

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/pvtDE

Comment: Oh, I probably forgot to tell you.. It's a chrome extension :DD, edited.. But it's popup in chrome extension

Comment: While you're editing, you might want to fix the JS typo.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions have sandboxing system for security reasons (eval is an big opened gate for hackers if isn't used properly), see [Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely.](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval)

Comment: I am not best in english. So basically, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the use of `eval` in your extension by [setting the content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval) to allow it.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

However, please read the page linked above fully to understand why it's not a very good (though sometimes valid) idea.

Comment: Ye, but I am making "hacking tool" extension :D

Comment: You are going to run into some bumps.. Read the [Acrhitecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Sure, because you're making another mistake. Try, for the first step, debugging it yourself? Right-click your extension button and select "Inspect popup". Hint: you will still need the page linked in my answer.

Comment: I don't quite believe that. You are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Gimme your skype, I'll send you extension file

Comment: I _see_ the error, I know the exact error it would generate, I've said how to find it. I don't need your code for that.

Comment: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: See? There was an error. Now, if you read the page, it will tell you how to fix it. Hint: `onmouseup`

Comment: Hey, I have another question to you, how to call function on <a href.. ? Because if i call it normally, it goes to 404 error, "Page ..extensionID/function(); doesn't exist" How to fix it? :) Thanks!

Comment: Btw: I am using mix of this and tinkernut's video :D
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",

Comment: Eh? var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
    button.onclick = function() {
      alert(1);
    };

Comment: Okay.. Leave your Skype in your profile (not here), I will contact you.